# Why is ASP.NET scaffolding template allowing an IEnumerable to access the property of individual items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

A bit of a confusing question here. I used the default scaffolding template for an Index View and it is strongly typed to my model. However, if my model is Employee, the view is actully strongly typed to the generic Employee type of IEnumerable , not just the Employee class._

In the default template for the table headers, the first argument of the Html helper method takes the lambda expression 'model => model.name' This doesn't make sense to me, because you would never be able to directly access the property of an individal item in a collection from the collection itself. It doesn't seem like it should even compile, is this correct?  How could that be explained?

Comment: Is your `Employee` class a simple class or it inherits from `IEnumerable`? Can you post your class definition? Because you can have an `Enumerable` and have a property directly on it (it would be a class property and not an item property however).

Comment: It's a simple class with only 4 properties and nothing else linked to a SQL table.  The Controller queries the table for all the records and converts it to a List of type Employee which is pased into the Index View.

Comment: And in your `*.cshtml` template there is no `for` or `foreach`?

Comment: Please post your code. It is difficult to give you useful advice if we can't see where you went wrong.